# how to fire the url of the custom button in Yii1.x after confirm box?

Tags: yii

I have a custom button something like

```
        'reject' => array(
            'label' => 'Reject',
            'imageUrl'=> Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/modules/mymodule/assets/images/icons/reject-icon.png',
            'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("mycontrollerName/reject/",array("id"=>$data->id,"asDialog"=>1)',
            'click' => 'function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to reject this data?")){
                        return false;
                    }
                 }
            '
        )
```

how to fire the url after clicking the 'ok' from the cofirm popup of javascript ?, did I lack something in the javascript?, or  ?

Comment: remove e.preventDefault(); from your code and try it.

Comment: nope...i figured it out after adding js:  ..beside the beginning of this javascript snippet